# react select async paginate TypeScript error: '=' expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

```js
  > 1 | import type { ReduceOptions } from './types';
      |             ^
    2 | export declare const reduceGroupedOptions: ReduceOptions<any, any, any>;
```

Getting this error in typeScript while using react select async paginate
Using this format.

```js
<AsyncPaginate value={value} loadOptions={loadOptions} onChange={setValue} />
```

loadOption

```js
 async function loadOptions(search: string, loadedOptions: any) {
    const response = await fetch(`/awesome-api-url/?search=${search}&offset=${loadedOptions.length}`);
    const responseJSON = await response.json();

    return {
      options: responseJSON.results,
      hasMore: responseJSON.has_more,
    };
  }
```

Comment: You can't do `import type { ReduceOptions } from './types';`, it should be `import { ReduceOptions } from './types';`

Comment: This error is from library itself.

Comment: This was due to version mis-match
See the list of version mapping in react-select-async-paginate and install correct versions of react-select and react.